# How to refresh graphics in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, refresh

I have a timer in a panel and when the timer ticks, it changes the coordinates of a rectangle.

I have tried two approaches:
1. Inside onPaint method,
2. Timer calls a function to create graphics and draw the moving rectangle

The first one does not work, but when I switch the windows, it moved once.

The second one works with problem. It is moving but leaving the previous position filled with color, which means the graphics are not refreshed.

I simply use `g.FillRectangles()` to do that.

Can anyone help me?

P.S. `the panel is using a transparent background.`

Added:
This is a System.Windows.Form.Timer

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.Enabled = false;
timer.Interval = 100;  /* 100 millisec */
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerCallback);

private void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x+=10;
    y+=10;

    //drawsomething();
    return;
}
```

1.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x, y, 100, 100);
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

2.

```
private void drawsomething()
{
    if (graphics == null)
        graphics = CreateGraphics();

    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x, y, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: please post your timer control event code.

Comment: try to use public virtual void Refresh();
[Check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: try this Form.ActiveForm.Refresh(); OR this.Refresh();

Comment: Hi, himanshu, both Refresh() simply fresh the whole form and the rectangle is not refreshed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `this.Invalidate()` in the TimerCallback event.

```
private void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x+=10;
    y+=10;

    this.Invalidate();
    return;
}
```

remove `drawsomething` function. it is not required here.

**Full Code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    int x;
    int y;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 100;  /* 100 millisec */
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerCallback);
    }
    private void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x += 10;
        y += 10;
        this.Invalidate();
        return;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x, y, 100, 100);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, but it works fine only for a simple rectangle. I applied it into my actual program and it fails to refresh.

Comment: have you enabled your timer control?

Comment: Yes, the rectangle keeps moving. but the old position is still colored.

Comment: `P.S. the panel is using a transparent background.` Why did you taken this panel?

Comment: I have a background picture in my form, and I need to have few areas in this form showing moving objects. Therefore I add a panel to control a specific area, but do not want it to cover the original background picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Invalidate` method. This method Invalidates a specific region of the control and causes a paint message to be sent to the control.

Details are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.panel.invalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MikeLischke: I agree with you, but the policy seems to be different. See [this question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: @MikeLischke: thanks for your comment. I am new in StackOverflow as answerer. Now answer is corrected.

Comment: @Truba, now that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of control class after redrawing. It

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately
>   redraw itself and any child controls.